# button linking to a page in a higher directory query

Tags: html, css

my button doesnt link to go to a page in a higher directory two file levels up any tips on how to do this? the file is in the folder:My_important_word_pages_and_iframepages_together:here is the file path:/home/pi/Documents/to be named the same then edited/edited and responsive/My_important_word_pages_and_iframepages_together/reads its own group/My_important_word_pages- and here is my line of code:

```
<li><a href="../../Choice_iframe.html" style="background-color:transparent;"><font style='font-style:regular;color:#00008B;font-weight:549'>Choice</a></li>
```

Comment: <li><a href="../../Choice_iframe.html" style="background-color:transparent;"><font style='font-style:regular;color:#00008B;font-weight:549'>Choice</a></li>

Comment: Plz add the code

Comment: I can't understand which file is where and what the problem is exactly? Can you give the file path to the file that contains the line of code you've shown and the file path that it's supposed to be loading when you click the link?

Comment: i dont know if this helps, i wrote a html page with an iframe and then linked the iframe to a page that is in the "My_important_word_pages and the page has links to other pages in the folder that i want to change so that i can change to another page in the "My_important_word_pages_and_iframepages_together" folder that is designed identically only with a link to another page in the "My_important_word_pages"

Comment: can i link from within the iframe to a new one and can i change the page to a new iframe page from within an iframe page instead then of having an iframe page within a iframe page that has the same headers on it hense a duplicate within a duplicate.

Comment: i would prefer to be on a new iframe page and exit the existing iframe

Answer (score 0):

And the name of the folder which is higher, like:

```
<li><a href="(folder_name)/(folder_name)/Choice_iframe.html">Choice</a></li>
```